# How to show system monitor in menu bar

Tags: macos, system-monitoring

I found the following image on the ChangLog, and I want to know how this person was able to display their system monitor information in their menu bar?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is most likely the 3rd party application [iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/).

[image: istat menus cpu]

[image: istat menus battery]